# What is the flight time limitation for commercial air transport operation in Europe?

Tags: airline-operations, easa-regulations

What is the maximum hours of flight time that a pilot can work legally in Europe? (daily, monthly and yearly)

Answer (score 2):

For EASA, flight times and duty periods are [limited (PDF p.25)](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/NPA%202010-14.pdf) to:

> ```
> (a) The total duty periods to which a crew member is assigned shall not exceed:
>   (1) 60 duty hours in any 7 consecutive days;
>   (2) 190 duty hours in any 28 consecutive days.
> (b) The total flight time of the flights on which an individual crew member
>     is assigned as an operating crew member shall not exceed:
>   (1) 100 flight hours in any 28 consecutive days;
>   (2) 900 flight hours in any calendar year;
>   (3) 1000 flight hours in any 12 consecutive calendar months.
> ```